# How to define new command for commands like \frac{} or \int{}^{}?

Tags: math-mode, macros

We know that we could define a new command for boldfaced or calligraphic C, for example I can define `\newcommand{\Cx}{\mathbb{C}}`, which will produce the boldfaced C, i.e. `$\mathbb{C}$` for me. But how do I define new command for say more complicated commands, e.g. `\frac{}{}` for getting fractions or say `\int{}^{}` for definite integrals? I tried defining `\newcommand{\fr(,)}{\frac{}{}}`, but it is not working. It seems to me there should be a correct way to define it.

Comment: Could you clarify **a)** what your new macro should do with **b)** how many parameters? A macro name like `\fr(,)` is almost not possible and would be very cumbersome to actually call in your document. Related: [Symbols to avoid while creating new commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34380) and [“Non-letters in macro names”](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=linmacnames).

Answer (score 8):

You can define a command with parameters:

```
\newcommand{\divbytwo}[1]{\frac{#1}{2}}
```

The `#1` is the placeholder for the first parameter to the macro: `\divbytwo{3}` will expand to `\frac{3}{2}`.

Edit: incorporating comments from the OP and @SašoŽivanović asking/answering about macros with more than one argument -

```
\newcommand{\divby}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}
```

will do the job. The `[2]` tells `TeX` how many parameters there will be. They're put in places `#1` and `#2`. Of course in this simple example`\divby` is just `frac` so you gain little by defining it.

Comment: Thank you, but can we handle two parameters together by any chance: something like: \newcommand{\divby}[1][2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}?

Comment: The optional argument of `\newcommand` (the number in square brackets) determines the number of arguments of the new command. So, in your case: `\newcommand{\divby}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}}`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "old" macro for the fractions (used in plain TeX):

```
{a\over b}
```

that produces the same result of

```
\frac{a}{b}
```

For integrals, I suggest you the following macro:

```
\def\intx#1{\int {#1}\,dx}
```

that produces the integral of #1 with its differential (where x is your variable)

Comment: Using `\over` is best avoided in LaTeX, and also `\def` is discouraged in document preambles.