# Problem inserting data in table using multiple files with catchfile

Tags: catchfile, definition

I have multiple data from different files that I want to use in the body of `tabular` environment. I saw a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26212089/how-to-read-body-of-table-from-a-separate-file), but the method only works for one such file only.

If the following was done

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}

\CatchFileDef{\mytable1}{table1.tex}{}
\CatchFileDef{\mytable2}{table2.tex}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
  \mytable1
  \mytable2
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It complains `Use of \f doesn't match its definition.`

`table1.tex` & `table2.tex` are formatted as follows

```
 a & b \\
  \hline
  c & d \\
  \hline
```

If only one such definition of table is used it works fine.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34380/symbols-to-avoid-while-creating-new-commands

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}


\CatchFileDef{\mytablei}{table1.tex}{}
\CatchFileDef{\mytableii}{table2.tex}{}

\newcommand\mytable[1]{\csname mytable\romannumeral#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
  \mytable1
  \mytable2
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Core issue being that digits are not (a priori) accepted by TeX in macro names. (I mean, without special set-up).

Comment: of course, one wonders now why using `\mytable1` and not `\mytablei` in document body...

Comment: you will need to use `\mytable{123}` if you have 10 or more tables, with braces.